# Change bounty description

Tags: support, bounty

I have just put a bounty on a question [Rewrite all *.php to single index.php before php-fpm processes it (apache)](https://serverfault.com/q/828679/81774) - canonical answer required and accidentally negated one sentence. I can't see a way to edit this. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you actually use search - I can't believe we don't have a [tag:mod_rewrite] Q&A that answers this already.

Comment: Hi, yes I did and reviewed many questions and answers. This is not about mod_rewrite, but about using mod_rewrite in .htaccess and **afterwards** parsing the **resulting** request file with php-fpm